# Can't fill staircase sides

Tags: mesh, edges

I need to fill this side and then other side of staircase, but tools I used don't work. Tools like **Bridge Edge Loops**, **Grid Fill** and **Fill** always make nosense mess like if there wasn't the same amount of verteces, but I checked it and there should be right number.

I use Blender 2.80.

[image: Staircase]

My thought is the problem do that pointing verteces on every step of starcase, but still don't know how to do that.

With Edge Loops, when I unselect edges on sides.
[image: edge loop]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there would be any automatic way to fill the side, you could do it this way: enable the *Snap* (Vertex mode) and the *Auto-merge* options, select the vertical raw of vertices and then make successive extrusions on the Y axis, it will automatically snap and merge.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got a good result selecting two edges (top and bottom ones) and hit  <kbd>F</kbd> .

I just forgot about the walls. The vertices will get disconnected the way I did it.

I think any automatic commands won't work because the steps and the wall have different loops.

[image]

The second try all worked fine using this method:

I removed some useles edges(I think).

Selected the edge loop and hit  <kbd>F</kbd> .

This created a big face.

Then I used the knife tool to connect the vertexes, completing the mesh.

**Edit:**

But You can select the vertexes and use the  <kbd>J</kbd>  to make a loop as said in the Robin Betts'comment. This is fastest than using the knife tool.

[image]

Comment: You could use the  'J'  join vertices operator, too, for doing it this way.. it can sometimes be less fiddly. It creates vertices where it crosses edges between the targets, OK.

Answer (score 1):

Knife Projection creates vertices at the intersections of projected edges, so if it saves enough labor, it can sometimes be useful for creating topology.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>Duplicate the perimeter, <kbd>P</kbd> separate it into a new object,<kbd>F</kbd> fill the original.

[image]

- <kbd>E</kbd> Extrude selections of vertices in the duplicate to create the grid. Don't worry about topology, duped faces, anything.

[image]

- In an (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>) orthographic view of the original face, 
  in Object Mode, select the the grid and then the face, throw them both into Edit Mode, and (Header > Mesh menu >) Knife Project the grid onto the face.

[image]

- Delete the grid, and you're done.

[image]